# High performance proxy for Linux

Tags: linux, proxy

Does anyone knows a transparent proxy high performance 200 users 100Mb/100Mb line,
I already run squid. I would like to test another on a Linux server.

Comment: Are you using squid as a forward or reverse proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Varnish always was more faster than squid and It will handle 200 users easily. here is a benchmark with 100 users http://dotimes.com/iscale/2008/04/benchmark-caching-of-varnish-and-squid-again.html (look at the comments)

Regards